# sim processing error please help

Tags: notifications

error pops up right before shutdown and right after powerup but only for a second then goes away. phone seems to work okay but what is this? how do I fix this?[image: phone info in link]

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't worry about it too much unless it was lasting too long. When you switch your phone on or off, the SIM is not detected yet (when switching on) or no longer detected (when switching off), that's why you get the error message. When it is detected and connected to your service provider, the error disappears.

If the error becomes permanent, then you will know that your SIM card probably is faulty and should be swapped to a new one.

Comment: thank you for the answer I really appreciate it Reddy

Comment: @dustin If and only if the answer is satisfactory, take the [tour](https://android.stackexchange.com/tour) on how to you can mark it as accepted and/or upvote it.